Google Cloud absence alert greater than 24 hours
I am trying to setup an alert in GCP that will trigger when logs are missing for 48hours.
I have a service that runs on a cron job on-prem, but submits logs to GCP when it runs. It only take a minute to run, but only needs to run every other day, potentially once a week. I need to ensure the cron job is running the task. We already have alerting pipelines/notification I want to use within GCP.
I believe the standard absence alert wont work for more than 23.5hrs, and I am hoping that someone out there has a novel workaround for this.
One idea is a GCP function that runs regularly (48hours/week etc), that simply scans the logs in the last window (48hours/week etc) and if it cant finds logs from my service it will spit out it own logs reporting the missing logs.
Then a logging alert could be setup to listen to 'missing logs' log from that function, and send an alert if it find one.
Is this stupid? Is there a way I could setup a monitoring metric for this for a long period? I feel it should be easy, but not seeing it.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks Pranay, while I appreciate the input about the current state, I am really looking for ways around the current limitations. In that regard your comment doesn't answer my question, and I am hoping that someone will provide/suggest a workaround.

FYI, I have created a cloud function that monitors the logs (the absense of logs), and it is working well. Would still be keen to hear opinions and other solutions though.

Are you able to share how you ended up doing the function that monitors the logs? Curious to implement something similar, as we want to do a 26 hour cycle.

I understand that you would like to know if there is a way to set the alignment window greater than 24 hrs and you believe that the standard absence alert only works for  23.5 hours. I would like to confirm that the safest standard absence alert only works for 23.5 hours. The current recommendation is not to use a duration greater than 23.5 hours for absence alerts. Please refer to this document for more information regarding this issue.
Please note that this is an ongoing request which has been notified to the product team and the product team is working on this request.
There is already a feature request for this. It does not have any ETA but clicking on the +1 in the top right will increase the popularity of the request and thus increase the chances of implementing this feature.
